# Why does Jetty consume more threads than specified in start.ini file?

Tags: java, jetty

I have my java spring application running inside Jetty 9.48.
These are the properties in start.ini file:

```
jetty.http.acceptors=30
# jetty.http.selectors=200

jetty.threadPool.minThreads=200
jetty.threadPool.maxThreads=1000
jetty.threadPool.idleTimeout=5000

jetty.http.host=0.0.0.0
jetty.http.port=8080
jetty.http.connectTimeout=2000
jetty.http.reuseAddress=true

jetty.lowresources.accepting=false

jetty.output.buffer.size=32768
jetty.httpConfig.outputAggregationSize=32768
jetty.httpConfig.requestHeaderSize=16384
jetty.httpConfig.responseHeaderSize=16384
jetty.httpConfig.sendServerVersion=false
jetty.httpConfig.sendDateHeader=false

jetty.server.stopAtShutdown=true
jetty.server.stopTimeout=5000
jetty.server.dumpAfterStart=false
jetty.server.dumpBeforeStop=false

jetty.deploy.scanInterval=0

jetty.console-capture.dir=/yyyy_mm_dd.stderrout.log
jetty.console-capture.retainDays=90
jetty.console-capture.timezone=UTC

jetty.debug.retainDays=90
```

When i run `htop` i see: "Tasks: 83, 3030 thr, 41 running".
And `ps hUH p <JETTY PROCESS PID> | wc -l` gives me 2876 jetty threads count.
Is it correct to compare these numbers with `jetty.threadPool.maxThreads`? If so, why maxThreads doesn't limit number of threads? And why there is such a big gap between existing and running threads?

To be clear, i expect Jetty to consume less memory. I assumed that huge amount of threads can affect it. Because at the moment jetty consumes almost all available memory (120/125G) but OOM is never happens.
I may not understand some of the basic concepts, but I would be grateful if you could help me figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jetty 9.x is now at End of Community Support (soon to be End of Life)

See: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/7958

---

You are not paying attention to what those threads are.

Jetty threads will have a name that start with `qtp`.

All other threads are from things that are not Jetty.